# How to use anaconda packages for python 3.7 on windows 10?

Tags: python, anaconda

Im on windows 10 Pro 64 bit version.

I download Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe from this page: https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

I double click the exe and follow the steps - I install it system wide at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3.

I launch the anaconda prompt. I create a virtualenv with conda create --name pythone37 python=3.7. I do conda install numpy (for instance)

Then I get :

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
C:\Users\Alex Marshall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.JKAMQ5EVHIVCPXP2XZJB2RQPIN47S32M.gfortran-win32.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alex Marshall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\Alex Marshall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\Alex Marshall\.conda\envs\python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

It seems to happen with any package that calls external C libraries (I think thats why its using WinDLL?). Also happens with numba for instance.

It does not happen with python3.6 or 32bit python. What gives? Is this just broken on windows for 3.7 64bit?

Comment: `C:\Users\Alex Marshall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37` this does not look like it is a directory that anaconda has created. Do you have any other python versions on your system? try to delete them all and start fresh

Comment: @FlyingTeller I have uninstalled all of them via the uninstall.exe command first. Is there something more that I have to do to uninstall them ?

Comment: Check if after that the folder `C:\Users\Alex Marshall\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37` is completely gone

Comment: @FlyingTeller its still there after running uninstall.exe. Other than deleting this is there anything else I can do to make sure everything is gone?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But you should be able to safely delete them